# Script Not Reading String

Tags: php, database, string, upload

I have a php script that uploads a profile picture to the server and then edits a field in the DB.

At the top of the script, I've added a line of code that will create a new folder in a directory, that's labeled by the user's id. The ID is echoed with $id. This works for the folder, but when I set the upload path to something like ../img/users/$id, it uploads to ..img/users instead.

CODE:

```
<?php 
require '../login_check.php';
include_once 'db_connect.php'; 
$dir = "../img/users/$id";
if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
mkdir($dir);
}
fclose($file);


$dir = "./users/$result[id]";
if( is_dir($dir) === false );

$path_to_image_directory = "../img/users/$id";
if(isset($_FILES['imgupload'])) 
{
$id = $_SESSION['id'];     
if ($_FILES["imgupload"]["size"] > 500000) 
{
header('Location: ../profile');
}
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(JPG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(PNG)|(png)$/', 
$_FILES['imgupload']['name'])) 
{
    $source = $_FILES['imgupload']['tmp_name']; 
    
    $randString = md5(time());
    $filename = $_FILES['imgupload']['name'];
    $splitName = explode(".", $filename);
    $fileExt = end($splitName);
    $newfilename  = strtolower($randString.'.'.$fileExt);
    $target = $path_to_image_directory . $newfilename;
     
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

    $updatestmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET profilepic= ? WHERE id = ?");
    $updatestmt->bind_param("si", $newfilename, $id);
    $updatestmt->execute();
    header('Location: ../profile');
}
else
{
   header('Location: ../profile'); 
}
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: move the line`$id = $_SESSION['id'];` before using the `$id` variable in `$dir = "../img/users/$id";`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti I did what you suggested, but it didn't make a difference. I assume this is what you were telling me to change?

Comment: $id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$path_to_image_directory = "../img/users/$id";
if(isset($_FILES['imgupload'])) 
{

Comment: Is the value $id is set??

Comment: Let me guess: saved file name is prefixed with user id, right? You should add `/` to enclose directory path, other way you concat dir path like `/path/to/dir` and `new_filename.txt` resulting in `/path/to/dirnew_filename.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $id variable before assigning $_SESSION['id'] value to it.
First you have to assign the value to $id

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Then use this $id to setting directory path variable.

```
$path_to_image_directory = "../img/users/$id";
```

Make sure your $_SESSION['id'] is not empty/null

Answer (score -1):

Move `$id = $_SESSION['id'];` to below `include_once 'db_connect.php';`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18872611)

Comment: I have edited it to be an answer. I only wrote it that way to offer alternatives to the person asking the question.

Comment: This is already done. It doesn't work though.

<?php 
require '../login_check.php';
include_once 'db_connect.php';  

$id = $_SESSION['id'];